# How do I print a different variable dependent on multiple quantity variables (and math)?

Tags: bash

Source File Input (.csv):

```
TOTAL FULL PARTIALORDER  FULLORDER  DEVICENAME
10    2    123456        456789     OHWIL8499IPM101
8     0    345678        789605     OHCIN8499IPM102
```

TOTAL= Is the total number of devices for a full and partial order.

FULL = A different order but of same location.

PARTIAL/FULL ORDER = Order numbers. I need to print one after each device name.

Requirement/Goal:

I need to subtract FULL from TOTAL. If there is a difference I need to change the order number variable on the last (# OF FULL) device names printed.

If there are 10 total and 2 full I need 8 devices printed OHWIL8499IPM101 through OHWIL8499IPM108 followed by the partial order number. Then OHWIL8499IPM109-110 followed by the full order number. In the input file example above the second line doesn't have a difference so I only need to print the partial order number.

Desired Output File (.csv):

```
DEVICENAME       ORDERNUMBER  SHIPDATE  TYPE      SYSTEMSKU
OHWIL8499IPM101  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM102  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM103  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM104  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM105  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM106  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM107  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM108  123456       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM109  456789       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
OHWIL8499IPM110  456789       ASAP      PROJECT1  12345678
```

Current Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentUser=$(/bin/ls -la /dev/console | /usr/bin/cut -d ' ' -f 4)
LOGFILE="/Users/$currentUser/Desktop/kit.csv"
SRCFILE="/Users/$currentUser/Desktop/input.csv"

orderFull=$(cat "$SRCFILE" | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $4}')
orderPartial=$(cat "$SRCFILE" | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $3}')
device_name=$(cat "$SRCFILE" | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $5}')
quantityNum=$(cat "$SRCFILE" | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $1}')
quantityFull=$(cat "$SRCFILE" | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $2}')
shipDate=ASAP
projectType=Project1
systemSku=1235678
number=$(echo "$device_name" | head -c 9| tail -c 4)

max_sequence_name=$()
max_sequence_num=$(echo $max_sequence_name | rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev)
if [ -z "$max_sequence_name" ];
then
    max_sequence_name=device_name
    max_sequence_num=100
fi
array_new_sequence_name=()
for i in $(seq 1 $quantityNum);
do
    cnum=$((max_sequence_num + i))
    array_new_sequence_name+=($(echo $device_name$cnum))
done
for sqn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]};
do
    echo "$sqn,$orderNumber,$shipDate,$projectType,$systemSku,$number" >> $LOGFILE
done
```

So far I have the following code I've been attempting to start with but am unsure if I'm on the right track or not.

```
if [ "$quantityFull" = 0 ]; then
  orderNumber=$(echo "$orderPartial")
else
  math=$(expr $orderPartial - $orderFull)
  #ENTER CODE HERE TO DETERMINE WHICH NAMES TO CHANGE ORDER NUMBER ON
  orderNumber=$(echo "$orderFull")

fi
```

Once this can be determined where would I place it in the above script? Or is there an easier way of implementing this somehow? If you need additional information please let me know.

Comment: Side note, unrelated to your actual question: can't you just use `$HOME` instead of the `/Users/$currentUser` contortions with parsing `ls -la` output?

Comment: Yes, although the thought never occurred until you mentioned it.

Comment: In our last echo, you are missing the closing `"`.  The line `orderNumber=$(echo "$orderFull")` can be replaced by `orderNumber=$orderFull`.  `curentUser=$(whoami)`.

Comment: Why `orderNumber=$(echo "$orderPartial")`?  What's wrong with `orderNumber="$orderPartial"`?  Why use `expr` instead of `math=$((orderPartial - orderFull))` ?

Comment: @Nic3500 Or just `$USER` - but since it's about accessing the home directory of the current user, `$HOME` makes sense.

Comment: @BenjaminW. indeed, $USER !  I picked up this whoami habit since I do so many switch users at work...

Comment: Nic3500 - That was just a type in the question. It wasn't that way in the script. Also, if that works I could go that route but it still doesn't help with the additional code needed to figure out how to print the right order number after the right device name.